# Setting security_opt in docker-compose.yaml doesnt work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, config

I'm trying to set `security_opt` according to official docker(docker-compose reference) docs. It doesnt seem to work from `docker-compose.yaml`. I've tried to google it but found weirdly limited amount of info about `security_opt` in docker.

I'm trying to start image with binary in `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    test:
        container_name: testcontainer
        image: testimage
        hostname: testhost
        command: --test
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data
        security_opt:
            - label:user:testuser
            - no-new-privileges:true
```

So when i run `docker-compose up -d` it starts this service from root, not from `testuser`.

But if i add `user: uid:gid` to the service config it starts from specified `uid`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    test:
        container_name: testcontainer
        image: testimage
        hostname: testhost
        command: --test
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data
        security_opt:
            - label:user:testuser
            - no-new-privileges:true
        user: 1001:1001
```

1. Why `security_opt` doesn't work?
2. What is the difference between `security_opt: - label:user:testuser` and `user: uid:gid`?
3. How can i check `security_opt` settings been applied?

It seems that not a lot of info about this topic on google. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `label` option under `security_opt` sets an SELinux label for the container. Whereas `user:uid:gid` sets the user-id and group-id to use for the container's main process.

Comment: ok so setting `user: uid:gid` of host system is enough to run securely from nonroot?

Comment: Looks like I missed your last comment; setting the `user:` option makes the container itself run as non-root, which means that the container process would only have non-privileged access to the host if it would be able to access things outside of the container (e.g. bind-mounts). It's also possible to run the docker daemon _itself_ in rootless mode, but it's more complex (and there are some limitations); see https://docs.docker.com/go/rootless/

Answer (score 7):

Answering "How can i check security_opt settings been applied?"

```
$ docker inspect [CONTAINER-NAME] --format '{{ .Id }}: SecurityOpt={{ .HostConfig.SecurityOpt }}'
```

To do it for all running containers:

```
$ docker ps --quiet --all | xargs docker inspect --format '{{ .Id }}: SecurityOpt={{ .HostConfig.SecurityOpt }}'
```